# how to eliminate repeating integers from cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have [words*sentences]matrix where sentences have integers that represent sentence numbers from a text document from this matrix i have constructed 1D array of [1*N] which shows words and in which sentences they occur number wise.
once above step is done i have taken intersection to check which words occur together in which sentences the code is as follows:

```
OccursTogether = cell(length(Out1));
for ii=1:length(Out1)
for jj=ii+1:length(Out1)
OccursTogether{ii,jj} = intersect(Out1{ii},Out1{jj});
end
end
celldisp(OccursTogether)
```

the sample output is as follows which shows 1st word occurs in sentence 
{5 10 16} same word occurs with 2nd word in sentence {11 12 13} and word 1 occurs with word 3 in sentence {9 14} and so on till the Nth word:

```
OccursTogether{1,1} = 5    10    16    
OccursTogether{2,1} = 5    12    16    
OccursTogether{3,1} = 9    14
```

now what i want is to show output in one line based upon OccursTogether cell array without repeating sentence numbers as below:

```
output: {5 9 10 12 14 16}
```

any help would me appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all cells which contain supersets of other cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099206/how-to-remove-all-cells-which-contain-supersets-of-other-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
result = unique([OccursTogether{:}]);
```

In your example this gives

```
result =
     5     9    10    12    14    16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `cellfun` and `cell2mat`. The idea is to vertically concatenate each cell form the cell array, convert it to a matrix and apply the `unique` function.

So the first step:

```
a = cellfun(@(x) x.',OccursTogether,'uni',false)
```

Takes each cell and transpose it, thus making a `n x 1` vector. The result is a cell array containing vertical vectors:

```
a = 

[3x1 double]
[3x1 double]
[2x1 double]
```

Now we can use `cell2mat` to convert to a numeric matrix since the dimensions will fit and finally apply `unique`. Otherwise that would not be possible (eg using 1x3 and 1x2 vectors).

In 1 line that looks like this:

```
output = unique(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x.',OccursTogether,'uni',false)))

output =

     5
     9
    10
    12
    14
    16
```

Hope this is what you meant! If not please tell me.

Comment: thanks for your answer, first step worked fine but when i tried to run 2nd step it gave me the error "Error using 'cat' Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent." i hope u understand the issue