# How to remove all cells which contain supersets of other cells?

Tags: matlab, subset, cell-array

I am working in text mining. I have 23 sentences that I have extracted from a text file along with 6 frequent words extracted from the same text file.

For frequent words, I created 1D array which shows words and in which sentences they occur. After that I took the intersection to show which word occurs with which each of other remaining words in sentence:

```
OccursTogether = cell(length(Out1));
for ii=1:length(Out1)
    for jj=ii+1:length(Out1)
        OccursTogether{ii,jj} = intersect(Out1{ii},Out1{jj});
    end
end
celldisp(OccursTogether)
```

The output is somehow like this:

```
OccursTogether[1,1]= 4 3
OccursTogether[1,2]= 1 4 3
OccursTogether[1,3]= 4 3
```

In above [1,1] shows that word number 1 occurs with word 1 in sentence 4 and 3, [1,2] shows word 1 and word 2 occurs in sentence 1 2 and 3 and so on.

What I want to do is to implement an element absorption technique, which will remove all cells which contain supersets of other cells. As we can see above 4 and 3 in [1,1] are subset of [1,2] so `OccursTogether[1,2]` entry should be deleted and output should be as follows:

```
occurs[1,1]= 4 3
occurs[1,3]= 4 3
```

Remember this should check all the possible subsets of entries in the system.

Comment: Do you want to remove all cells which contain supersets of other cells?

Comment: @2cents yes i want to remove all cells which contain supersets of other cells

Comment: I would make that your title. It's a more general problem statement that more people might be familiar with.

Comment: Why don't you remove entry {1,3} as well? [4 3] is an (improper) superset of [4 3]

Comment: @LuisMendo u are rite i will remove that entry as well by using unique once i am done with superset removal

Comment: @2cents sure i will update my title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(OccursTogether));
s = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x,y)), OccursTogether(ii), OccursTogether(jj));
s = triu(s,1); %// count each pair just once, and remove self-pairs
result = OccursTogether(~any(s,1));
```

*Example 1*:

```
OccursTogether{1,1} = [4 3]
OccursTogether{1,2} = [1 4 3]
OccursTogether{1,3} = [1 4 3 5];
OccursTogether{1,4} = [1 4 3 5];
```

gives

```
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
     4     3
```

`OccursTogether{1,2}` is removed because it's a superset of `OccursTogether{1,1}`. `OccursTogether{1,3}` is removed because it's a superset of `OccursTogether{1,2}`. `OccursTogether{1,4}` is removed because it's a superset of `OccursTogether{1,3}`.

*Example 2*:

```
OccursTogether{1,1} = [10 20 30]
OccursTogether{1,2} = [10 20 30]
```

gives

```
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
    10    20    30
```

`OccursTogether{1,2}` is removed because it's a superset of `OccursTogether{1,1}`, but `OccursTogether{1,1}` is not removed even if it's a superset of `OccursTogether{1,2}`. The comparison is done only with previous sets (third line of code).

Comment: This code returns an empty set if there is a cell with only one element e.g `{14}` `{15}` etc, can you plz help me to resolve this issue. on multiple elements it gives good results only issue is with single elements- thanks

Comment: I don't get that result. For example. `OccursTogether = {[4 3], [1 4 3], [3]}` produces the result `{[4 3], [3]}`

Comment: at my end the output is `similarity{1} = []` can u predict the reason of this output. is this due to different data set having no subsets remaining

Comment: can you please test on this dataset, i have this dataset on which it is showing empty output                                                 `OccursTogether{1,3} =9    14    17`
    `OccursTogether{1,4} =16`
    `OccursTogether{1,5} =11    16` 
    `OccursTogether{2,5} =[]`
    `OccursTogether{3,5} =11`

Comment: If _one of the inputs if empty_ you do get an empty result, because every set is a superset of the empty set

Comment: okay, can u please help me to filter out all the empty sets first and than apply your proposed technique.

Comment: To remove the empty sets initially: `OccursTogether = OccursTogether(~cellfun(@isempty, OccursTogether));`

Comment: thanks luis this worked for me but there is another issue that i faced now, does order matters if 3 element set occurs before 2 element set?
i gave input as `[5] [4 11 14] [1] [5 16] [11 16] [11] [16] [9 14 17] [14]` and the output was `[5] [4 11 14] [1]  [11 16] [11] [16] [9 14 17] [14]` as u can see there are still super sets present
the desired output should b like  `[5] [1] [11] [16] [14]` i hope u understand the issue